# How to give a javascript made checkbox an onchange event?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox, onchange

Hey I'm trying to create a few checkboxes in javascript and add them to my html. I want to give the checkboxes an onchange event but the event only fires when they get created and when the site is loaded and I click on the checkboxes nothing happens. As well if I look into the source code of the site in the browser there is no onchange event at the checkboxes.

hashtags is an Array with objects with some properties but they aren't important

```
hashtags.forEach(element => {
    if(element.categorie == searchedCategorie && element.beitrage == searchedSize && element.language == searchedLang){
        searchedHashtags.push(element.hashtagName);
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.className = "checkboxes";
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.value = element.hashtagName;
        checkbox.onchange = handleChange(checkbox);
        checkbox.name = element.hashtagName;
        label.appendChild(checkbox);
        label.innerHTML += element.hashtagName;
        body.appendChild(label);
        body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
});



function handleChange(checkbox){
if(checkbox.checked == true){
    countChecked++;
}else if(checkbox.checked == false){
    countChecked--;
}
txtarea.innerHTML = countChecked + "/" + searchedHashtags.length + " ausgewählt";
alert(countChecked);
```

}

Comment: Solved it with setAttribute(), but i don't know how to delete a question? :D

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to solve this Error if you replace

```
checkbox.onchange = handleChange(checkbox)
```

with

```
checkbox.setAttribute("onchange","handleChange(this)");
```

Comment: This line of code may be the solution, but there is no context.  Including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Does your code suggestion replacing `checkbox.onchange = handleChange(checkbox);`? with your suggestion.